# type punning with template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, type-punning

I had to check someone's clumsy code that used 20+ unions and  according number of methods that were punning and copy data from and to an byte array, in order to implement those methods through template (second for a char)

```
template <class T> class type_punner
{
    T& p;
    unsigned char* pun;

public:
    type_punner(T&  ref): p (ref), pun(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&p))
    {
        static_assert(std::is_pod<T>::value, "type_punner can be used only for POD");
    }


    inline unsigned char& at(std::size_t  i)
    {
#ifdef QT_DEBUG
        if(!(i < size())) throw std::out_of_range( __FUNCTION__ );
#endif
#if (Q_BYTE_ORDER == Q_LITTLE_ENDIAN)
        return pun[i];
#else
        return pun[size() - i - 1];
#endif
    }

    inline unsigned char& reverse_at(std::size_t  i)
    {
#ifdef QT_DEBUG
        if(!(i < size())) throw std::out_of_range(__FUNCTION__);
#endif
#if (Q_BYTE_ORDER == Q_LITTLE_ENDIAN)
        return pun[size() - i - 1];
#else
        return pun[i];
#endif
    }

    // = 0 is  LSB
    inline unsigned char& operator[](std::size_t  i)
    {
        return at(i);
    }

    inline std::size_t size()
    {
        return sizeof(T);
    }
};
```

Only what I worry about that  if I'm staying  standard compliant and  assigning new values via returned references is valid.

Comment: Well, it is in any case undefined behavior, as per the Standard goes. It's your job to make sure you don't spawn hydras.

Comment: @DeiDei I don't spawn hydras  actually, that's not worst example of  creating hydras by co-workers. what happened with rule about casting to character type pointer and so on? Really, ungrounded comments like that aren't helpful, btw, there is no way around is as  A) purpose is to display data and to pack it in either reverse or straight order B) nothing but C++ is available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code appears legal.  There are a few improvements:

```
constexpr bool k_little_endian
#if (Q_BYTE_ORDER == Q_LITTLE_ENDIAN)
  = true;
#else
  = false;
#endif
constexpr bool k_debug
#ifdef QT_DEBUG
  = true;
#else
  = false;
#endif

template <class T,
  bool little_endian = k_little_endian,
  bool debug = k_debug
>
class type_punner {
  T* p;
  unsigned char* pun() const { return reintepret_cast<unsigned char*>(p); }
public:
  static_assert(std::is_pod<T>::value, "type_punner can be used only for POD");
  type_punner(T& ref):
    p (std::addressof(ref))
  {}
  type_punner(type_punner const&)=default;
  type_punner()=delete;

  unsigned char& at(std::size_t i) const noexcept(!debug) {
    if (debug && !(i<size())) throw std::out_of_range( __FUNCTION__ );
    if (little_endian)
      return pun()[i];
    else
      return pun()[size() - i - 1];
  }

  unsigned char& reverse_at(std::size_t i) const noexcept(!debug) {
    if(debug && !(i < size())) throw std::out_of_range(__FUNCTION__);
    if (little_endian)
      return pun()[size() - i - 1];
    else
      return pun()[i];
  }
  // = 0 is  LSB
  unsigned char& operator[](std::size_t i) const noexcept(!debug) {
    return at(i);
  }
  static constexpr std::size_t size() noexcept(true) { return sizeof(T); }
};
```

First, this moves the macros out of the way.  Code that is what you are looking at tends to be easier to reason about, and compilers are perfectly capable of eliminating dead branches.  It is rarely an idea to store a reference unless you want reference semantics on your type, and it is almost never a good idea to store a reference *beside a non-reference* in the same class/struct.

Second, inline in class bodies is redundant.

Third, `size` is both constexpr and static.

Forth, `T&` with default copy/assign doesn't do anything reasonable.  `T*` does.  So I used `T*`.

Fifth, no need to store `pun`.  Generate it each time for zero cost.

Note that the above `type_punner` can experiment with a `little_endian` one in a big endian environment, or turn debugging on only for one part where you are having problems.  The cost for this is a tiny compile-time one.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting about reference field! good idea about moving macros,  `constexpr `not supported,  but `const` should be enough.. I used macro definition that inserts it in case if we upgrade, and for one of two compilers used inline isn't redunadant (it never expands without inline, or  it expands EVERY function) and doesn't stores reference in class, static_assert() works only function bodies, no default or deleted methods supported. I certainly would experiment with generated  pun() instead

Comment: what's  noexcept(!debug) ? never saw that before

Comment: @Swift It stats "this is a guaranteed not to throw if `debug` is false, but may throw if `debug` is true."

Comment: ah.. looked it up. not supported either, only throw() is, but good to know.

Comment: on additional thought, with that  template parameter  I do not need reverse_at anymore. at and reverse_at are never used in same context, so I can just declare punner with !k_little_endian. more hydra heads had fell

Comment: @Swift The benefits of killing macro-filled code are many, some of them not intended ("bonus")

Answer (score 0):

> Only what I worry about that if I'm staying standard compliant and assigning new values via returned references is valid.

It is valid, because those references are of narrow character type, which are special.